# Obtener menor y mayor numero de los datos de un arreglo en C#

Tags: c#

Se que para algunos esta puede ser una pregunta demasiado fácil, pero estoy empezando apenas en esto de la programación. El ejercicio se trata de obtener el mayor y menor valor de 15 datos. Mi problema es que no puedo obtener el valor mínimo de todo el arreglo y necesito de su ayuda para saber cuál es mi error, este es el código:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ventas = new int[15];
        int v, max = ventas[0], min = ventas[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("ingresos en ventas: ");
            v = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            ventas[i] = v;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            if (ventas[i] > max)

                max = ventas[i];


            else if (ventas[i] < min)

                min = ventas[i];
        }   

        Console.Write("\n\nLa mayor venta es: " + max);
        Console.Write("\n\nLa menor venta es: " + min);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

La salida en cosola solo muestra el mayor valor, pero con el menor sucede que siempre es 0.

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Qué tal con `var menorDeTodos = ventas.Min();`? Para esto vas a requerir `using System.Linq;`. Lo mismo pasaría para encontrar el mayor usando `var mayorDeTodos = ventas.Max();`

Comment: tu fallo es que haces min = ventas[0]; antes de dar valores al vector, por lo tanto min coge el valor de 0. Haz min = ventas[0] una vez dados los valores y con max deberías hacer lo mismo porque se inicia en 0 y si rellenas el array con números negativos te dará mal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma es usando Linq:

1. `var menorDeTodos = ventas.Min();`: encontrará el valor mínimo.
2. `var mayorDeTodos = ventas.Max();`: encontrará el valor máximo.

Tu código quedaría algo como esto:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] ventas = new int[15];
    int v, max = ventas[0], min = ventas[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("ingresos en ventas: ");
        v = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        ventas[i] = v;
    }

    Console.Write("\n\nLa mayor venta es: " + ventas.Max());
    Console.Write("\n\nLa menor venta es: " + ventas.Min());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Para esto es necesario que hagas referencia a la librería de Linq `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Muchas gracias man, estuve toda la tarde intentando resolver este ejercicio y pensar lo fácil que era. Te lo agradezco en serio.

Comment: @Larjos aclarar que si tu pregunta es una tarea escolar o algo similar, probablemente esta solución no guste a tu profesor. Se trata de que aprender la forma de hacerlo, no usar un método que ya lo hace por ti :)

Comment: Desde mi punto o de vista, y con todo respeto, aunque la respuesta es correcta, no es adecuada para el op puesto que parece obvio que es un ejercicio o tarea, y en esos casos no creo que sea una respuesta adecuada. La otra respuesta explica en que falla el codigo. Ahora, si no es un ejercicio/tarea, entonces si es adecuada.

Comment: Entiendo. Sí se trataba de una tarea, finalmente la envié con la primera respuesta ya que contaba con poco tiempo. Gracias igualmente, ambas respuestas y sus comentarios me ayudan a mejorar.

Answer (score 2):

aunque te han dado una respuesta, te voy a decir porque falla tu codigo.

Tu problema esta que asignas a las variables min y max los valores antes de leer los datos por lo que min y max se inicializan a 0

si cambias un poco tu codigo, funcionara.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ventas = new int[15];
        // int v, max = ventas[0], min = ventas[0]; VENTAS[0] ESTA SIN INICIALIZAR y tienen el valor 0
int v;
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("ingresos en ventas: ");
            v = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            ventas[i] = v;
        }
        int  max = ventas[0], min = ventas[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            if (ventas[i] > max)

                max = ventas[i];


            else if (ventas[i] < min)

                min = ventas[i];
        }   

        Console.Write("\n\nLa mayor venta es: " + max);
        Console.Write("\n\nLa menor venta es: " + min);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, aunque el ejercicio ya lo he enviado, esto me ayudará a identificar futuros errores y mejorar mi lógica de programación.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui les dejo otra respuesta similar a la anterior para determinar numero mayor y menor de una lista

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] array = new int[5];
        int numero; 
        for (int i = 0; i <array.Length ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese numero: ");
            numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            array[i] = numero;
        }

        Console.Write("\n\nEl numero mayor es: " + array.Max());
        Console.Write("\n\nEl numero menor es: " + array.Min());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

La combinación de sentencias condicionales con variables y ciclos permite de una manera intuitiva hallar el mayor o menor de un conjunto de datos, así entonces, es posible pensar:  si "a" es mayor que "b" entonces el nuevo mayor sera "a" y generalizar como si "b" es mayor que "mayor" entonces el nuevo valor de "mayor" sera "b"

Comparto un programa en visualStudio c# para determinar el mayor y menor valor de un vector
https://tutorias.co/arrays-visualstudio-c-hallar-el-mayor-y-menor-valor-de-un-vector/